# How to do multiple indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, indices

[image]I am trying to do multiple indices. However, it is showing the error of too many indices. Please help me and if you have some doubts or confusion in it then please leave comments in the comment box.

My result has (6561114,) shape and I want to indices the whole first row  for instance ([array([-1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.]), array([[43.,  0., 43.,  1.,  2.]]), array([-43.,  43.,   0.,   2.,   3.]) and then from 3 columns I want to extract each value of array-like [-1,43,-43],[1,0,43], and so on.

```
This is Output:-
array([array([-1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.]),
       array([[43.,  0., 43.,  1.,  2.]]),
       array([-43.,  43.,   0.,   2.,   3.]), ...,
       array([-1.406830e+01,  3.552240e+01,  2.145410e+01,  
        9.492236e+06,
        9.492237e+06]),
       array([[1.421949e+02, 2.145410e+01, 1.636490e+02, 9.492237e+06,
        9.492238e+06],
       [3.387300e+01, 1.636490e+02, 1.975220e+02, 9.492238e+06,
        9.492239e+06]]),
       array([-1.9052487e+02,  1.9752200e+02,  6.9971300e+00,  
        9.4922390e+06,
        9.4922400e+06])], dtype=object)

This is what error looks like:-

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-537ba6ddfd42> in <module>
----> 1 result1[0,:]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: Sorry, there might be format issue in my post.

Comment: Your array is one dimensional but you are asking for the second dimension.

Comment: Would you suggest how to do that?

Comment: Try to reproduce the error with a smaller array... It seems like your array is one dimensional but you are asking for the second dimension.

Comment: I got you. Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: `result1` is a 1d array containing arrays.  They vary in shape, some appear to be (5,), one at least is (1,5), and another (2,5).  `np.vstack(result1)` might produce a 2d array of floats, joining all those sub arrays.  `ravel` does not 'flatten' this kind of array.  You can fetch individual arrays with `result1[0]` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check in second array you are using 2 [] braces.

Here  `array([[43.,  0., 43.,  1.,  2.]])` you are using 2 [] braces, remove [] braces, and use it

I am using this code, and its working fine

Check using print(a[0]) and post your output.

### Code

import numpy as np

a=np.array([np.array([-1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.]),np.array([43.,  0., 43.,  1.,  2.]),np.array([-43.,  43.,   0.2.,   3.])],dtype=object)

print(a[:,0])